# Clipboard copy-paste in JavaScript doesn't work in Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, microsoft-edge, zeroclipboard, clipboarddata

I am aware of the fact that Clipboard API is currently not supported by edge browser. I am using document.execCommand() to do copy & paste. The copy functionality works fine. But the paste doesn't work. I am using a custom context menu to achieve copy and paste. Previouly I made use of Clipboard API for the functions, it was working flawlessly until Edge came up. I heard Clipboard API will be added in next Edge release. I even checked Zero clipboard from GitHub. But didn't get an appropriate way to implement "Paste" functionality. I just want to know is there any alternate way to achieve the same or by using ZeroClipboard.